# How can I make sure when I put a new number in input field the script/ <p> tag refreshes?

Tags: javascript

So I have this script, when I input a number and press the button it says if its a prime number or not, but when I put a new number the `<p>` tag does not refresh, it keeps the result of the first input.

```
var primeResult;
var number;

window.addEventListener("load", Init);
 
function Init(){
number = Number(document.getElementById("PrimeNumb").value);
primeResult = document.getElementById("PrimeResult");
let primeButton = document.getElementById("btn");
primeButton.addEventListener("click",IsPrime);
}

function IsPrime()
    {
        var i,flag=0;

        for(i=2; i <= number/2; i++)
        {
            if(number%i == 0)
            {
                flag = 1;
                break;
            }
        }
        if(flag == 0)
        {
            primeResult.innerHTML = number + " is een prime nummer!";
        }
        else
        {
            primeResult.innerHTML = number + " is geen prime nummer!";
        }
    }
```

Comment: you could listen to the onChange event on the input and update the DOM accordingly

Answer (score 0):

You can use an event handler on the input, such as `change` or `input`

```js
document.getElementById("PrimeNumb").addEventListener('input', IsPrime);
```

Comment: Changed my answer, I wasn't aware this behaved differently to the change event.

Answer (score 0):

Oke So I have fixed it, I put the ```let number = Number(numberElement.value)````in the IsPrime Function and it solved my problem

Answer (score 0):

You have the `init` method on page load initializing your `number` variable. Hence it always checks if the the first value is prime.

You can add the `isPrime` event handler directly on the input element like Josh mentioned or you can change your `isPrime` method to always get the current number value like you already have it in your `init` function.

```
number = Number(document.getElementById("PrimeNumb").value);
```